# Final Fantasy XV Install Time

Tags: psn, final-fantasy-15

So I bought Final Fantasy XV Digital Premium Edition off the PSN.

I installed the file but I can't click "New Game", even though the game is installed. In the Final Fantasy XV Application, it still says in the top right corner: "Instal Time Remaining: 1,896min" And that number keeps going *up* not down.

What's going on here?

I don't have PlayStation Plus and 224GB of free space. A number that notably isn't changing no matter how long Final Fantasy XV "installs".

Comment: Yes it sucks. Like call of duty it will let you go on the game with the minimum amount of it installed, and then it will begin installing the rest. And once you finish that you have to download a few internal game updates. Its normal don't worry. Are you able to access any other features?

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket Yeah I can do Open Combat. (Which is definitely not why I bought the game.) Is there a reason that the download is so slow though? My download speeds are much higher than what the game is downloading at. I currently have 63hrs to go :(

Comment: Well im not sure but try disconnecting your playstation from the internet to be sure thats its actually downloading, because its likely just installing from the disc without the use of internet.

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket I still see a section in the downloads menu, showing it being downloaded. I'm currently downloading at a rate of 1MB/44sec

Comment: There's nothing that you can do except either buy new internet or wait a year, and maybe it will be half way done . You don''t want your PS4 to overheat as well so be wary of that.

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket It looks like the UVerse router has problems with the download of games on the PS4. I've included a link in my answer to others experiencing the same problem. For me the solution was a simple modem reboot. But I still say that we all take this opportunity to shake our collective fists at AT&T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ATT Uverse, and apparently I'm not the only one with this problem: https://forums.att.com/t5/AT-T-Internet-Equipment/AT-amp-T-U-Verse-PS4-Connection-Speed-REALLY-SLOW/td-p/3837651#M16995

It didn't seem to be related to the service though, I the tech assured me that I wasn't being throttled.

My speed started in accordance with my bandwidth, but after downloading enough to start the app, I still needed to download more of the app to actually start a new Final Fantasy XV game, then my speed became throttled (1MB/44sec)

**Strangely all it took for me to fix this was to restart the modem.** Which didn't make sense because all the other devices in the house had fine connection speed. This may also make the question/answer off topic, but I'll leave it here in the hopes it may be helpful to someone else.